# using htaccess to replace a character

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

URL including a % symbol can't pass through my existing htaccess (i get a 400 error) but there is no problem without the php page. I need to find a way to use htaccess to replace the % symbol by something else, then my PHP script will convert them back to %.

The htaccess would need to convert this:

> http://www.example.com/test%20test%blah%blah

to this:

> http://www.example.com/testXXX20testXXXblahXXXblah

Then my PHP script will convert the XXX back to %.

using B flag doesn't work.

Comment: Just tell me: *why* ?

Comment: What is your current mod rewrite configuration?

Comment: "*there is no problem without the htaccess*" - so fix whatever in your htaccess is breaking things!  Why on Earth would you settle on replacing with some arbitrary string as a solution?  What would happen if that arbitrary string existed in the URL?  This is a classic example of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)!

Comment: `%blah` is not a valid URL, no wonder something breaks. Your problem may be even deeper.

Comment: @AnarChoi post your `.htaccess` so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: First, i meant there is no problem with my PHP page. http://example.com/page.php?f=test%test works perfectly so don't tell me it isn't a valid URL. I get a 400 error only when using htaccess to rewrite http://example.com/test%test to http://example.com/page.php?f=test%test... The % won't pass through the htaccess and i get a 400 error. So i need to find a way to use htaccess to replace % by something like @XYZ@ then once it reach my PHP file, it will reconvert it back to %.

Comment: `%20` is a standard character escaping in a URL. It represents a space character, and when your PHP program gets it, it will see a space, not `%20`. You should not be trying to change how `%` works in a URL; it works that way for a reason. A `%` on its own in a URL (as you have between blah and blah) is invalid; this will create errors. If you meant to have a space, you should use `%20`, not just `%`. If you wanted a `%` sign on its own, it would need to be encoded to `%25`.

Comment: I know it will create error with htaccess, that's why i want to replace it with other characters. I have no control over the URL and their characters (too long to explain why) and i can't replace/escape the characters before they reach my server. Please just tell me how to replace % by XYZ using htaccess. The PHP file will reconvert them to % so it won't change how the $ works.